# Rethrowing an exception out of Scatter-Gather flow in Mule ESB

Tags: exception, mule, mule-component

I have a very specific question, and i really searched the answer all over the place... 
Here is a situation: i have a Scatter-Gather component with a custom aggregation strategy.
 
http://clip2net.com/s/j66jK8 - Image of a subflow
Semantic of this process is rather simple. Request comes with Basic Authentication Header, the upper road calls just empty java processor, which returns original payload, the lower road authenticates user over LDAP, and returns Boolean result of this authentication process. Custom aggregation class checks result and if authentication was OK, then returns original payload, which results from the road #1. If not OK, then throws exception. Nothing wrong here, it works.

There is a bit tricky thing. If a user passed wrong authentication data then exception occurs in ldap:bind module. According to documentation exception is propagated to the Scatter-Gather so i'm trying to catch it using this:

```
@Override
public MuleEvent aggregate(AggregationContext context) throws MuleException {
    for (MuleEvent event: context.collectEventsWithExceptions()) {
        event.getMessage().getExceptionPayload().getException().printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage().getExceptionPayload().getException());
    }

    MuleEvent result = DefaultMuleEvent.copy(context.getEvents().get(0));       
    if (!(Boolean) context.getEvents().get(1).getMessage().getPayload()) {
        throw new SecurityException();
    }       

    return result;
}
```

BUT!
As a result i see exception which stacktrace does not have `javax.naming.AuthenticationException` which was rased by ldap:bind component, and was printed to log automaticaly (see below).

So, my question is: how can i reach and rethrow this javax.naming.AuthenticationException exception out of Custom Aggregation Class?

I'd appreciate all you ideas and help. Thank you in advance.

```
WARN  2014-10-15 20:51:18,552 [[minkult].ScatterGatherWorkManager.02] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Bind failed.
ERROR 2014-10-15 20:51:18,559 [[minkult].ScatterGatherWorkManager.02] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: cn=sim,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com]; resolved object com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@5de37d66. Type: class javax.naming.AuthenticationException
COUNT: 1
org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException: route number 1 failed to be executed. Failed to route event via endpoint: InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for processor chain 'null'' 
[ 
  ScriptComponent{CheckAuth.component.553657235}, 
  org.mule.module.ldap.processors.BindMessageProcessor@647af13d, 
  org.mule.module.ldap.processors.SearchMessageProcessor@2aac6fa7, 
  InvokerMessageProcessor [name=ldapUtils, object=com.at.mkrf.aggregate.LDAPUtils@5714c7da, methodName=findGroupByName, argExpressions=[#[payload], #[systemName]], argTypes=[Ljava.lang.Class;@5af349a6]
]. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
```

Comment: you can try to play around with custom-exception-strategy, that is define your own exception strategy for the flow(create java-class which would extend DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy), and in the doHandleException method propagate this exception

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The real problem occurs far outside the exception block. I cannot get the right exception even in Custom Aggregator, that's much closer to it's source, then exception block.

Answer (score 0):

On a `CompositeRoutingException`, you can call:

```
exception.getExceptions().values()
```

to get an `Array` of `Throwable`s thrown from within the scatter-gather. Then just re-throw the appropriate exception.